# Choose model by BIC in a stepwise algorithm after choosing model from glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have data where number of observation `n` is smaller than number of variables `p`. The answer variable is binary. For example:

```
n <- 10
p <- 100
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol = p)
y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
```

I would like to fit logistic model for this data. So I used the code:

```
model <- glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", intercept = FALSE)
```

The function returns 100 models for different $\lambda$ values (penalization parameter in [LASSO](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/lasso/simple.html) regression). I would like to choose the biggest model which also has `n - 1` parameters or less (so less than number of observations). Let's say the chosen model is for `lambda_opt`.

```
model_one <- glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", intercept = FALSE, lambda = lambda_opt)
```

Now I would like to do the second step - use `step` function to my model to choose the submodel which will be the best in term of BIC - Bayesian Information Criterion. Unfortunately the `step` function doesn't work for objects of the `glmnet` class.

```
step(model_one, direction = "backward", k = log(n))
```

How can I perform such procedure? Is there any other function for this specific class (`glmnet`) to do what I want?

Comment: If I recall correctly, lasso methods are often used to "replace" stepwise methods. I'm unsure whether it makes sense to perform a stepwise procedure following a lasso procedure.

Comment: I am doing some simulations and it seems that generally if I choose model from glmnet with lambda_min from cv.glmnet it is still too big. So I came up with this approach.

Comment: I agree with @David, this doesn't make sense. If you wish to use a smaller model, choose a higher penalty. Or choose a submodel within the results from the full Lasso path.

Comment: ... But, to directly answer your question, I think you'd need to write your own step function. `step` is written to work with classes `lm` and `glm`

Answer (score 3):

BIC is a fine way to select a penalty parameter from the sequence returned by glmnet, it's faster the cross validation and works quite well at least in the settings where I've tried it.

- Compute the residuals sum of square for each value of the penalty parameter in the sequence (use `predict(model,x)` to get the fit)
- `model$df` gives you the degrees of freedom.
- Combine those to get a BIC and pick the value of lambda corresponding to the lowers BIC.